# React Native support date

Tags: react-native

Does anyone knows until when React Native is supported? I was trying to find an answer online but it was not possible to find anything related to supported dates.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if there is a set date that they are planning to drop support?

Comment: Yes.. I could not find anything about it online for any of platforms (Android / iOS).

Comment: There are no plans to drop support. In fact, they are actively adding new features and fixing bugs, and the framework is getting more and more popular. I do not see them support dropping any time soon, though of course there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

**React Native isn't getting dropped in the near future.**

Currently Facebook is pushing its framework. They try to release every 2 weeks a new version with bugfixes and features. [react-native release process](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/05/22/react-native-release-process.html)